# S3 xml file with special chinese/arabic characters downloading with question mark instead of character

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, encoding

I have an some files in xml that I'm uploading to s3 that contains special characters in different language. I'm uploading the file as follows using the amazon.s3 library for dotnet:

```html
 PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = GetBucketName(),
                Key = MakeS3Key(entry.Token, entry.AlternateKey),
                FilePath = path,
                ContentType = entry.MimeType + ";charset=utf-8"
            };
            putRequest.Headers.ContentEncoding = "utf-8";
            if (publicRead)
                putRequest.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;

            using (var client = ConnectToS3())
            {
                PutObjectResponse response =         client.PutObject(putRequest);

            }
```

I'm including charset=utf-8 in the content type and the contentencoding, however when I download from s3 the characters in notepad have question mark where I'm including a special character in a different language. Is there  workaround for this issue? The file seems to save correctly when I save it to disk.